# How to get column values in output with logstash

Tags: logstash

I am working with a csv file and logstash. I am able to get the column values in the filter but I am not able to get those value in the output. The config file I am using is like:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/B0079855/Documents/SERVERS/logstash-2.2.2/samples/products.csv"
    # to read from the beginning of file
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["COL1", "COL2"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Is it possible to get the column values in the output as well?

Answer (score 0):

What if you have the [CSV](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html) filter as below.

```
filter{
    csv {
        fields => ["COL1", "COL2"]
        separator => ","   <---------add this  
    }
}
```

Comment: This didnt work. The configuration you shared will generate a csv file and also it will need a path parameter for where the file needs to generated.

Comment: So what you need is to just get the column values out?

Comment: Yes. In case I get the fields in the output I can use them the way I want.

Comment: @Karan I've updated the answer with the separator. Try adding it to your filter. After that check indexing it, and whether you've got the csv values in ES.